# Very weird problem with Javamail after updating Jetty from 9.3 to 9.4

Tags: java, jetty, jakarta-mail

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport cannot be cast to com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport
```

Pretty self explanatory why this is dumbfounding. I use Javamail, probably using old jars but they always worked fine so I saw no reason to update. I use these files for Javamail : activation.jar  dsn.jar  imap.jar  mailapi.jar  pop3.jar  smtp.jar.

Everything worked fine until I updated to Jetty 9.4 and started getting this weird errors. The very strange thing is that I only get these errors sometimes when a mail is sent by a listener, all mails send by servlets work fine but *some* of the mails set by listeners provoke this error.

I noticed that in 9.4, jetty includes an other implementation of Javamail in the lib folder. I tried to delete this file and then I started getting errors "no such transport". I tried to put my javamail files into the lib/ext folder, and then I started getting the com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport cannot be cast to com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport error again.

I simply don't understand how the Jetty class loader works, sometimes I must duplicate jar files both into $JETTY_BASE/lib/ext folder and my WEB-INF/lib folder, but most of the time if I duplicate the file in both folders, I get a warning.

I tried to use jetty's Javamail implementation to replace my old files, but it simply did not work so I gave up.

I'm starting to run out of ideas to solve this problem, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show us your `${jetty.base}` configuration. edit your question and add the output of the following ...  `$ cd /path/to/myJettyBase && java -jar /opt/jetty/jetty-home/start.jar --list-config`

Comment: If Jetty is providing JavaMail, you shouldn't have one in your application.